# What is this Swift code doing? func somefunc(where: (_: NSLayoutConstraint) -> Bool)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm used to Objective-C but not Swift. I understand the very basics of Swift and I tried to read docs and grasp it myself but can't. What confuses me is the function declaration, I don't get what's going on, what arguments (or other function?) it does accept and what it does with `where` inside. If someone could translate it in terms of Objective-C that'd be great and it'd explain it to me.

```
// extension of UIView
    func removeFirstConstraint(where: (_: NSLayoutConstraint) -> Bool) {
         if let constrainIndex = constraints.firstIndex(where: `where`) {
              removeConstraint(constraints[constrainIndex])
         }
    }
```

And this is how it's called in other parts of code (a subclass of UIView):

```
trackView.removeFirstConstraint { $0.firstAttribute == widthAttribute }
```

and

```
removeFirstConstraint(where: { $0.firstAttribute == oldConstraintAttribute && $0.firstItem === self && $0.secondItem == nil })
```

Which also confuses me because of the difference and the usage of `where`.

Answer (score 2):

The `removeFirstConstraint` function argument is what is called a closure, ie. a function.

More on closures here : https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html .

In your case, the closure must have the signature `(_: NSLayoutConstraint) -> Bool`, ie. it should take a `layoutConstraint` as argument and return a boolean.
So, for your case, the `removeFirstConstraint` function will call the closure on every constraint of the UIView, and remove the first that, when passed as argument to the closure, will return true.

---

The two calls of the function are equivalent, you can pass a closure as a normal argument for the function,

```
trackView.removeFirstConstraint (where: { /*closure code*/ })
```

or simplify this way :

```
trackView.removeFirstConstraint { /*closure code*/ }
```

$0 represents the first argument of the closure.
Hence, the code

```
trackView.removeFirstConstraint { $0.firstAttribute == widthAttribute }
```

will remove the first constraint whose `firstAttribute` is equal to `widthAttribute`.

---

Oh, and in the code

```
func removeFirstConstraint(where: (_: NSLayoutConstraint) -> Bool) {
         if let constrainIndex = constraints.firstIndex(where: `where`) {
              removeConstraint(constraints[constrainIndex])
         }
    }
```

the `where` closure passed as argument to the `removeFirstConstraint` function is directly passed to function `firstIndex`, which also takes a closure as parameter. `firstIndex`, called on an array, returns the index of the first item that makes the closure return true.

The quotes around `where` are necessary because where is a swift keyword, so it must be escaped to be used as an identifier.